# SNAP out of control

Tags: snap, lxd

I'm running many LXD containers inside a specific developer area , this morning I found some container stuck and I turned out that SNAP has updated the LXD at the version 3 automatically.

As far as I've understood is not possible to stop the autorefresh so I suppose that SNAP is not for production environment.

Is there a way to stop the autorefresh using a specific firewall rule at least?

Thanks.

Comment: You could go back to the 2.0 branch of lxd and stay on it with `snap refresh lxd --channel 2.0/stable`

Comment: thanks a lot  , although is not exactly what I would like to have , this can help.

Answer (score 0):

You can also set the refresh schedule of snapd using `sudo snap set system refresh.timer=4:00-7:00,19:00-22:10`. See this for more details: https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/system-options/87